# W2GRID: Save changes automatically when the user modify a cell value

Tags: javascript, user-interface, datagrid, javascript-framework, w2ui

I'm using the **w2grid** widget on [inline editing](http://w2ui.com/web/demos/#!grid/grid-21) mode.

My program needs save changes to database each time the user introduces a new value into the cell grid.

To do this, I defined a `onChange` event to the grid, and when `onChange` is triggered the [`save()`](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/w2grid.save) method is called:

```
onChange: function(event) {
    w2ui[event.target].save();
}
```

The problem is that the `save()` method sends old data values to the server (It doesn't send the last update). At the first modification `getChanges()` array is empty. And the next `onChange` event will not send the last modification, but the previous modified values.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found what I'm doing wrong.

The documentation says about the [events](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/utils/events):

"*By default all event handlers are triggered **before** the default behavior is processed.*"

"*You can also define a function that will be executed **after** the default behavior is processed.*"

**So, for waiting until the event change is completed:**

```
function (target, event) {
    event.onComplete = function () {
        w2ui[event.target].save();
    }
}
```